# Postgres 11: fastest way to convert a small list of numbers to text (to be used as NOTIFY payload)

Tags: postgresql, trigger, datatypes, type-conversion

I am on Postgres 11.5 and in a trigger function I issue one or more `pg_notify` calls for each row modified in the transaction. The most common payload is a list of 12 `float` numbers, representing two edges of two 3D points each. Additionally, there are a project ID `integer` and a short update type string, e.g. the values `1, 'edges', 0.0, 1.0, 2.1, 3.2, 4.3, 5.4, 6.5, 7.8, 8.7, 9.8, 10.9, 11.0` would be a common payload. I can change the exact format used and so far, I called `pg_notify` like this to create a JSON string:

```
pg_notify('catmaid.spatial-update','{"project_id": ' ||
    t.project_id || ', "type": "edges", "edges": [[[' ||
    t.location_x || ',' || t.location_y || ',' || t.location_z || '], [' ||
    t.px || ',' || t.py || ',' || t.pz || ']], [[' ||
    t.otx || ',' || t.oty || ',' || t.otz || '], [' ||
    t.px || ',' || t.py || ',' || t.pz || ']]]}')
```

During the optimization of this trigger function (thanks `auto_explain` for the trigger plans!), I noticed that the `pg_notify` call adds a substantial amount of time to the query. On my production system this trigger typically runs for updates on 5-10k rows at a time many times a day. The test case I worked with had 9500 rows to update (= number of `pg_notify` calls). My trigger function takes about 1800ms for these 9500 rows. If I remove the `pg_notify` call it's only 270ms. However, if I only use strings during the concatenation (rather then the numeric row values) or alternatively use only a single string as payload, the function runs in 360ms, which makes me think that not the concatenation, but the casts from `float` to `text` might be the bottleneck (or the parser is clever and combines the string constant only concatenations).

Also, it turns out that a `pg_notify` call that doesn't use `||` for string concatenation, but `concat_ws()` to create a string from my number is faster:

```
pg_notify('catmaid.spatial-update', concat_ws(',',
    '[', t.project_id, 'edges', '2', t.location_x, t.location_y,
    t.location_z, t.px, t.py, t.pz, t.otx, t.oty, t.otz, t.px, t.py, t.pz, ']'))
```

This takes only 1100ms (reproducible) and I am not sure it is only because of the slightly fewer concatenations or fewer intermediate strings. Still, it would be nice if I could get this 1100ms closer to the 360ms with strings only and therefore I wonder if there are faster ways to create a `pg_notify` payload than what I have written above.

Comment: what about `to_jsonb(t)` instead to convert the complete row to JSON?

Comment: Great idea, no clue why I didn't try that before. I just posted a comment, claiming it would now run in 400ms, but this turned out to be wrong. Using `pg_notify('catmaid.spatial-update', to_json(t)::text)` runs in ~1650ms, i.e. it isn't as fast as `concat_ws()`.

Comment: You could also try `row_to_json()` - maybe that's faster. But in the end notify isn't really intended to carry large payloads. Can't you just send the table name and the primary key value in the payload?

Comment: Thanks, but I tried `row_to_json()` too and it's the same as `to_json()`. You are right, I might not get around sending around pointers to a table and the doc's max 8000 bytes per payload was too tempting. The original hope was to "emit" all required information for a cache update with before and after information (using transition tables). But given that I also have already a history tracking system in place, pointing to history entries for the "before" part should work fine, it just means more coupling.

Comment: And interestingly, if I only send a simple string as payload the timing is ~360ms, but if I only use a single number (primary key) of a changed row with explicit `::text` cast, it is already at 1100ms (like the longer `concat_ws()` version above). It seems even a single cast is problematic.